# Discriminator for TABLE_PER_CLASS

Tags: hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

I have the following JPA mapping.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@DiscriminatorColumn
public class BaseEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
    private Long pk;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private BaseEntity parent;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="sclBase")
@DiscriminatorValue("sclBase")
public class SclBase extends BaseEntity {
    private String attr;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="scls")
@DiscriminatorValue("scls")
public class Scls extends BaseEntity {
    private String attr;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="scl")
@DiscriminatorValue("scl")
public class Scl extends BaseEntity {
    private String attr;
}
```

So each entity could have a parent of type not-known at compile time. Since table_per_class hierarchy is used BaseEntity table would not be generated but its attributes would be duplicated in each child class. So each child class would have the following fields: pk - primary key, attr - some attribute, parent_id - reference to the parent. But parent id would not be a foreign key, since we don't know which table it's referencing.

So when I want to obtain a parent of the entity Hibernate/EclipseLink would iterate through all entities until it will find the entity with the given parent_id. Not very effective, is not it? The procedure could be much simpler if store parent_type as discriminator column. So the parent would be found by parent type and parent_id.

Is there a way to make hibernate/EclipseLink generate this discriminator column to improve performance?

Comment: FWIW I'm pretty sure DataNucleus JPA would generate a discriminator column in that situation, since you did take the time to request one.

Comment: Will the entities always have an entity of the same type as a parent?? for example, will the parent of an Scl always be an Scl??

Answer (score 0):

In EclipseLink you can use an @VariableOneToOne mapping for this.

But, in general you may wish to reconsider your usage of TABLE_PER_CLASS, it is inefficient compared with the other inheritance strategies.

See,
http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_variableonetoone.htm